# Every derived table needs an alias

Tags: sql

Here's my code, I need the Full names and salaries of faculty with lowest salary from every department. My subquery works on it's own, but I can't get the rest to work together.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) AS 'Faculty',DepartmentID,Salary
FROM Faculty,
(SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentID AS 'Department', MIN(Salary) AS 'MinSalary'
FROM Faculty GROUP BY DepartmentID)
WHERE Faculty.DepartmentID= 'Department' AND Salary= 'MinSalary'
ORDER BY DepartmentID
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to pud alias on your subquery

```
SELECT CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) AS 'Faculty',DepartmentID,Salary
FROM   Faculty,
       (
        SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentID AS 'Department', 
               MIN(Salary) AS 'MinSalary'
        FROM Faculty GROUP BY DepartmentID
       ) xx    -- <<< this is the alias. (Don't forget this)
WHERE Faculty.DepartmentID= 'Department' AND Salary= 'MinSalary'
ORDER BY DepartmentID
```

`xx` is the name of your subquery in the example above. (*and I think the query is not giving you the results you want*)

To modify your query for better performance, (*Assuming you are using `MYSQL` because of `CONCAT` function*)

```
SELECT  CONCAT(a.FName,' ',a.LName) AS FacultyName,
        a.DepartmentID,
        a.Salary
FROM   Faculty a
        INNER JOIN
       (
        SELECT DepartmentID , 
               MIN(Salary) AS MinSalary
        FROM Faculty 
        GROUP BY DepartmentID
       ) xx    -- <<< this is the alias.
        ON  a.DepartmentID = xx.DepartmentID AND
            a.Salary = xx.MinSalary
-- WHERE .. (add extra condition here)
ORDER BY DepartmentID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74b4a/1)

**UPDATE 1**

It might also be `SQL Server 2012`. (*already supports `CONCAT()`*)

```
SELECT CONCAT([FName], ' ',[LName]) FullName, [DepartmentID], [Salary]
FROM
  (
    SELECT [FName], [LName], [DepartmentID], [Salary],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY DepartmentID
                              ORDER BY Salary) rn
    FROM Faculty
  ) x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/285af/2)

Answer (score 2):

As the error message in the title hints, Standard SQL requires sub-queries in the FROM clause to have names.  You should also learn to use the JOIN notation, not the comma-separated list of table names.  You need to know the old (pre-SQL92) notation to recognize it; you should not use it yourself.

```
SELECT CONCAT(F.FName, ' ', F.LName) AS 'Faculty', F.DepartmentID, F.Salary
  FROM Faculty AS F
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentID AS 'Department', MIN(Salary) AS 'MinSalary'
          FROM Faculty
         GROUP BY Department) AS D
    ON F.DepartmentID = D.Department AND F.Salary = D.MinSalary
 ORDER BY F.DepartmentID;
```

Comment: Who knows; there was a pile of unnecessary downvoting, and I'm not even clear who did it, and most certainly not why.  Thanks for the rescue vote.

Answer (score 0):

Your derived table needs a name which is what the error message is complaining about (see `YouNeedToPutATableAliasHere` below):

```
SELECT CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) AS Faculty,DepartmentID,Salary
FROM Faculty,
(SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentID AS Department, MIN(Salary) AS MinSalary
FROM Faculty GROUP BY DepartmentID) AS YouNeedToPutATableAliasHere
WHERE Faculty.DepartmentID= 'Department' AND Salary= MinSalary
ORDER BY DepartmentID
```

Note I've also removed some single-quotes where they didn't make sense to me. (Perhaps you meant double-quotes, square brackets, or backticks for column names, but single quotes probably won't work - you may need to do the same for 'Department'?)

---

You will also be creating a Cartesian join unless you specify conditions correlating the two tables. A better query for "faculty with the minimum salary in the dept `'Department'`" might be (note I have removed the redundant GROUP BY):

```
SELECT CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) AS Faculty,F.DepartmentID,F.Salary
FROM Faculty F
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DepartmentID, 
    MIN(Salary) AS MinSalary
    FROM Faculty 
    GROUP BY DepartmentID
) AS MinSal ON MinSal.DepartmentID = F.DepartmentID 
            AND F.Salary = MinSal.MinSalary
WHERE F.DepartmentID= 'Department'
ORDER BY F.DepartmentID
```

Or, since you are only selecting the one department `'Department'`, you could do:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) AS Faculty,F.DepartmentID,F.Salary
FROM Faculty F
WHERE F.DepartmentID= 'Department'
AND F.Salary = (
    SELECT MIN(Salary)
    FROM Faculty 
    WHERE DepartmentID = F.DepartmentID
)
```

Or even (which would also work for multiple departments but may be slower than a join):

```
SELECT CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) AS Faculty,F.DepartmentID,F.Salary
FROM Faculty F
WHERE F.DepartmentID= 'Department'
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Faculty FF
    WHERE FF.DepartmentID = F.DepartmentID
    AND FF.Salary < F.Salary
)
```

---

In fact, in looking at your original query and in an effort to make this question complete while reading @RichardTheKiwi's comments, I will incorporate that interpretation into this answer. This assumes you are using MySQL (from the CONCAT function) and that you meant *backticks* instead of forward ticks for column names. It also assumes you wanted the minimum-salaried faculty for *every* department, not just the specified one as 'Department'. It just requires a *small* change from my first suggested query though - namely the removal of the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) AS Faculty,F.DepartmentID,F.Salary
FROM Faculty F
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DepartmentID, 
    MIN(Salary) AS MinSalary
    FROM Faculty 
    GROUP BY DepartmentID
) AS MinSal ON MinSal.DepartmentID = F.DepartmentID 
            AND F.Salary = MinSal.MinSalary
ORDER BY F.DepartmentID
```

Comment: Serial downvote anybody? WTH? You could at least comment so I can *improve my answer*...

Comment: looks like that, I've got -1 too without comments. Not very brave to downvote answer without explaining your point

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi And who's to say that's even a mistake?? It's in the original question's query which had *absolutely nothing to do with `'Department'`, but explaining how to fix a "Every derived table needs an alias" error. Note I've even edited my answer a little to add an explanation. I humbly and completely disagree my original answer was **wrong**, but in the hopes of going *above and beyond being helpful* I have added these notes and comments.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi AFAIK my answer are/was correct except one alias of the table, and I've corrected it without your downvote. Actually it become strange when smbd asks an question and gets 5 almost identical queries as answers in less then a 3 minutes :) I think we need more complicated questions here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT CONCAT(F.FName,' ',F.LName) AS Faculty, F.DepartmentID, F.Salary
    FROM Faculty F
    JOIN (
            SELECT DepartmentID,
                   MIN(Salary) AS MinSalary
              FROM Faculty
          GROUP BY DepartmentID
         ) G
      ON F.DepartmentID = G.DepartmentID AND F.Salary = G.MinSalary
ORDER BY F.DepartmentID
```

The problem with using single-quotes around alias names is that you fall into the trap evident in your query - your first `WHERE` condition is matching DepartmentID against the `string` literal **'Department'**.  This goes too for the **'MinSalary'** column.

Of note also is the fact that GROUP BY does not need DISTINCT - because you are already getting distinct values of DepartmentID.

And to the first problem that brought you here - each derived table (aka sub-query) needs an alias, or something with which to identify the columns from it.  In the example below, you can see that the first part of the ON clause compares two `DepartmentID` columns.  The aliases `F` and `G` are imperative here to distinguish between the two, hence the requirement to alias each table.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs an alias for subquery

```
select
    concat(F.FName, ' ', F.LName) as Faculty,
    F.DepartmentID,
    D.MinSalary
from faculty as F
    inner join
    (
        select T.DepartmentID, min(T.Salary) as MinSalary
        from Faculty as T
        group by T.DepartmentID
    ) as D on D.DepartmentID = F.DepartmentID and D.MinSalary = F.Salary
order by F.DepartmentID
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use aliases for both table and the subselect query table:

```
    SELECT CONCAT(F.FName,' ',F.LName) AS Faculty,F.DepartmentID, F.Salary
    FROM Faculty F,
     (SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentID AS Department, MIN(Salary) AS MinSalary
      FROM Faculty GROUP BY DepartmentID) AS DEP_MIN_SALARY
    WHERE F.DepartmentID= DEP_MIN_SALARY.Department 
          AND F.Salary= DEP_MIN_SALARY.MinSalary
    ORDER BY FDepartmentID;
```

**One observation:** You are not retrieving any columns from the derived table. Hope that is intentional.